# Meaning of $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2+h)-g(2-h)-16}{h}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, polynomials

> - $g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & (x<a) \\ x^4 & (x \ge a) \end{cases}$
> - $f(x)$ is differentiable in every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I was solving a math problem, and I've approached this formula : $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2+h)-g(2-h)-16}{h} \, (\text{when }a=2)$$
The solution says this can be altered into $32-f'(2)$, but I keep getting $32+f'(2)$.

Here's my approach:

1. Since $a = 2$, $g(2) = 16$.
2. So, the formula becomes
   $$ \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2+h)-g(2-h)-g(2)}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2+h)-g(2)}{h} - \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2-h)}{h} \\ = 32 - \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(2-h)}{h} \\ = 32 - \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(2-h)}{h} \\$$$$= 32 - \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(2-h) - f(2)}{h}\tag{*} $$$$\\ = 32+ \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(2-h) - f(2)}{-h} \\ = 32+ \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(2+h) - f(2)}{h} \\= 32 + f'(2)$$

Is this the right answer? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did the f(2) in ( *) come from? I edited your post to include the ( *).

Comment: @insipidintegrator I thought $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(2-h)}{h}$ would exist, and since the denominator goes to $0$, numerator also has to go to $0$. So $f(2)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the denominator goes to zero, this places the restriction that $g(2+h)-g(2-h)\to 16$ in the numerator when $h\to 0^{+}$. If this isn't the case, we have that the limit DNE. If it is indeed the case, that is,

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}(2+h)^{4}-f(2-h)=16$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}(2+h)^{4}-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}f(2-h)=16$$

$$16+f(2)=16$$

$$\therefore f(2)=0$$

as you stated in the comments.

Perhaps we can gain insight by taking another route. We can apply L'Hôpital:

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{g(2+h)-g(2-h)-16}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{g'(2+h)-g'(2-h)(-1)}{1}$$

(-1 factor comes from derivative of $2-h$ due to chain rule.)

$$=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{d(2+h)^4}{dh}+\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}f'(2-h)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}4(2+h)^3+f'(2)=32+f'(2)$$

Assuming $f$ isn't a pathological function, its derivative is continuous, which is why we're able to take $\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}f'(2-h)$.

I also see no problem with your analysis... The answer is probably $32+f'(2)$. It may be that you got your signs mixed up since the limit

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{g(2+h)+g(2-h)-16}{h}$$

*does* actually equal $32-f'(2)$, if we assume $f(2)=0$.

If you aren't convinced by analysis, perhaps a numerical example will help. Consider $f(x)=x-2$. Clearly $f(2)=0$ and it is a differentiable (and not pathological) function everywhere. Here $32-f'(2)=31$ and $32+f'(2)=33$, yet

$$\frac{g(2+0.001)-g(2-0.001)-16}{0.001}\approx 33$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! But I've read the question properly. Maybe the solution in the book has a typo...